# How do I query for empty MultiValueField results in Django Haystack

Tags: django, search, elasticsearch, django-haystack

Using Django 1.4.2, Haystack 2.0beta, and ElasticSearch 0.19, how do I query for results which have an empty set `[]` for a MultiValueField?

Answer (score 2):

I'd create an integer field named `num_<field>` and query against it.

In this example 'emails' is the MultiValueField, so we'll create 'num_emails':

```
class PersonIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')
    emails = indexes.MultiValueField(null=True)
    num_emails = indexes.IntegerField()

    def prepare_num_emails(self, object):
        return len(object.emails)
```

Now, in your searches you can use

```
SearchQuerySet().filter(num_emails=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change `prepare_` method of your `MultiValueField`:

```
def prepare_emails(self, object):
    emails = [e for e in object.emails]
    return emails if emails else ['None']
```

Then you can filter:

```
SearchQuerySet().filter(emails=None)
```